# Are there any advantage to having a high galactic readiness rating in multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In Singleplayer, the rating affects the outcome of the ending of the game.

However, does it make any difference in multiplayer?

Comment: In single player, it does not affect the outcome of the game at all.

Comment: @Hugo. It does. The "best" ending can only be seen when choosing the renegade option and having 5500+ effective military strength. If you don't play multiplayer at all or use none of the smartphone apps, you can only reach 4000 or something of effective military strength, as far as I'm aware (I myself played a 100% ME1 and ME2 character, completed pretty much everything of ME3 and was at about 4000).

Comment: You are wrong. I got slightly over 5500 military strengh, using a character imported from ME1->ME2. I got all three "choices" at the ending.  My guess is that you need to complete all side-quests. But I finished the single player mode a week after the game came out, and only started playing multiplayer yesterday, so rest assured, MP did *not* affect my galactic readiness.  I was actually surprised most people got only two "choices" at the end, since this was the only run I did of ME3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Galactic Readiness has no effect on Multiplayer.

That doesn't quite cover it though; there *is* no Galactic Readiness in multiplayer (you *earn* it, but it doesn't change anything). Galactic Readiness exists solely within Single Player.

**But**, if you've *maxed* Glactic Readiness, you get an XP bonus at the end of a match instead of a readiness boost.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in playing multiplayer it is better to keep your readiness at 100%. Because in doing so you get an extra 5% experience from every match played. But other than the bonus experience you get, it is only useful for solo play.